# Match one of the elements of an array in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I'm trying to create a function that returns true if at least one of the elements of a string array is found within another string.

```
function findInString(str) {
    var fruits = ["orange", "banana", "grape"];

    for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        if (str.indexOf(fruits[i]) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

var a = findInString("I love orange juice."); //=> returns true
var b = findInString("I don't like peach."); //=> returns false
```

This function does the trick, but I'm sure there might some array or string method that does the same without having to loop through the array. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might consider posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Code Review would probably want to see what the actual code is. This really seems like example code asking for a different way to do the same thing (i.e. a specific programming question) which is better fit on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You _have_ to iterate over the complete array _somehow_ otherwise the solution won't be complete.

Comment: You'd only have to iterate over the whole array if you don't find any.

Comment: haha this one kinda blew up a little bit, clearly there are TONS of ways to do this! good one

Comment: Actually, I was wrong in my last comment because `some` breaks if a match is found and doesn't continue any further.

Comment: Note I was intrigued by the challenge and did some limited testing. A split of the string into an array and comparison of the two arrays was actually faster AFTER about a 100 threshold point in my very limited tests.  So your current options are faster until you process that same string a good number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually I can't think of a better (or even different) way of doing this. I don't know of a built in function which performs this task but even if there was one it's implementation would be this anyway.

Comment: So far this is been the best answer... I wanted something to make what I did simpler and the answers that I'm getting are making it more complicated :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `some` which comes very close to this. Here's how I'd write it:

```
function find (str, arr) {
  return arr.some((s) => s.indexOf(str) > -1); 
}
```

You could do this as well if you'd like but I don't feel good about it.

```
function find (str, arr) {
  return arr.join(',').indexOf(str) > -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like your way of doing it. I got a little into it, here are several ways you can think about doing this:

Some of these are really close, but that last period might require some string parsing to handle every case. Note the last one, since it uses RegExp, wont require doing anything to the string:

[JsBin Example](https://jsbin.com/welati/5/edit?js,console)

```
function findInString(str) {
  var fruits = ["orange", "banana", "grape"];

  return str.split(' ').filter(function(el) {
    return fruits.indexOf(el) > -1;
  }).length > 0;
}

function finderWithReduce(str) {
  var fruits = ["orange", "banana", "grape"];
  var result = false;
  str.split(' ').reduce(function(a, b) {
    if (a.indexOf(b) > -1) {
      result = true;
    }
    return a;
  }, fruits);
  return result;
}

function finderWithForEach(str){
  var fruits = ["orange", "banana", "grape"];
  var result = false;
  fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
    if (str.indexOf(fruit) > -1) {
      result = true;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

function finderWithRegex(str) {
  var fruits = ["orange", "banana", "grape"];
  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var re = new RegExp(fruits[i], 'gi');
    if (str.match(re) !== null) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `some` function.

```
function findInString(str, arr) {
   return arr.some(function(el) {
      return str.indexOf(el) > -1;
   });
}

var fruits = ["orange", "banana", "grape"];

var a = findInString("I love orange juice.", fruits); //=> returns true
var b = findInString("I don't like peach.", fruits); //=> returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you do have to process the array.  I would make two changes.

First I would pass in the array as well as the string, making a generic function, then I would rework it so that once it finds one it quits doing that and exits the loop; similar concept as the return true but just a differing way to do it - my personal preference to only have one function exit.

```
function findInString(arr, str) {
  var hasString = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    if (str.indexOf(fruits[i]) > -1) {
      hasString = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return hasString;
}

var fruits = ["orange", "banana", "grape"];

var a = findInString(fruits, "I love orange juice."); //=> returns true
var b = findInString(fruits, "I don't like peach."); //=> returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional ES6 method. `presentIn` is a higher-order function that takes a string and returns a function that acts as the `some` callback.

```
const presentIn = (str) => (el) => str.includes(el);

fruits.some(presentIn('I love orange juice.')); // true
fruits.some(presentIn('I don\'t like peach.')); // false
```

I really like this approach because you're operating directly on the array elements, and if you name your function well it scans brilliantly: "Are some elements of the array present in the string".

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qtt5sq8o/3/)

The slightly more verbose ES5 version for comparison:

```
function presentIn(str) {
  return function (el) {
    return str.indexOf(el) > -1;
  }
}
```